# How can you edit image urls and display them in react-admin

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-admin

I want to be able to iterate over all urls in a series of objects and edit them so they are visible on a `react-admin` panel that's using `react-admin-firebase` to populate the `DataProvider`.

I have a bunch of urls from firebase storage that I want to display in an admin panel. Trouble is, firebase stores those file locations at a relative path, and not a public-accessible path. i.e. something like `gs://imagename.png` and not the downloadable url like `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/imagename.png`.

I've tried using the `useQuery` and `useDataProvider` hooks from `react-admin`, but they seem to return data that isn't applicable: for `useQuery` I tried a `getList` type and empty payload obj and got back an empty array. for `useDataProvider` I get the whole data provider object and none of the actual data.

Also when I tried passing in dynamic values to the `ImageField` component, I got an error saying `source` prop must be of type `string`. I thought [based on their docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#imagefield) I should be able to make a custom object and pass it in as props to `ImageField`, but no `img` elements show up in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

There is (currently) no way to load data from `gs://` URLs in web clients.

If you want to display images from Cloud Storage in your web app through Firebase, you will need to [get the download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url) for each file and show those in your `img` tags.

Comment: thanks, I've done so in my actual app but I thought in the react-admin-firebase system there may be some way to handle this more easily. I am trying to figure out how to get access tot he raw `gs://...` url and change it to a public one and pass it into `Field` components. I think I'll have to do it via a `CustomField` component.

Comment: Even if you mark the field as public, you will need to get a public URL for it. I don't think a custom field is needed, as you can get a download URL from the `gs://...` URL as shown in the link I shared.

Comment: Hey @crevulus. Anything else needed here?

Comment: yes, as the issue is rather a react-admin one than a GCP/FB one.